# pyparsing - parse scoped variables

Tags: pyparsing

So far, I was able to use pyparsing to parse ebnf grammars.
However, I wanted to try the following code sample but could not come up with 
a good grammar.

```
global radius = 5
DrawCircle(radius)
{
  radius = 10
  DrawCircle(radius)
}
DrawCircle(radius)
```

The value of radius with in the scope should be 10, 5 otherwise.
Any help would be appreciated ?

Regards

Praveen

Comment: I think this question goes far beyond a basic parsing issue. Once you have this parsed, then you have to have a proper execution environment, which would respect the scoping of variables. That is where the work should go, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Will do the same. Once parsed, I will leave it up to the parse action to actually distinguish the global and local variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the parser for the above code by running:

```
enclosed = Forward()
curls = nestedExpr('{', '}', content=enclosed)
enclosed << (OneOrMore(commands | ',' | curls))
```

I have a follow up question. I am used to write ebnf grammar using http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/ebnf.py

Can I get some help identifying the ebnf for forward or equivalent of the above code ? or should I do outside ebnf ?

Regards

Praveen

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing